# como faço pra ver uma branch no github

Tags: github

Olá

Como faço pra ver uma branch no github remoto?

Poderiam me ajuda, por favor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Maria Heloisa bem vinda ao SO-pt, recomendo que você dê uma lida nas diretrizes sobre perguntas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: na captura de tela você já está vendo a branch, não tenho certeza qual a sua dúvida, você pode explicar detalhadamente? Note que é possível editar a pergunta e adicionar os detalhes.

Comment: Para poder ver a branch no GitHub é preciso enviá-la para o servidor. Faça um `push` de uma  branch local, por exemplo.